# DNS and Authoritative Answer bit

Tags: networking, dns

As I understand it, in order to know a the DNS answer is authoritative or not the "Authoritative Answer" bit is used. My questions now are:

1. When is the bit set (under what circumstances or conditions)?
2. By whom is it set? Manually by the server administrator or automatically by the server?

Answer (score 3):

See [RFC 1035 § 4.1.1. Header section format](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt):

```
AA              Authoritative Answer - this bit is valid in responses,
                and specifies that the responding name server is an
                authority for the domain name in question section.

                Note that the contents of the answer section may have
                multiple owner names because of aliases.  The AA bit
                corresponds to the name which matches the query name, or
                the first owner name in the answer section.
```

Essentially this bit will be if the queried DNS server believe that it is authoritative for the queried name. This usually implies that the queried DNS server is listed as nameserver for the queried name's zone, i.e., has a NS RR entry in the queried name's zone.

It hasn't to do anything with being the primary (master) or secondary (salve) nameserver. All nameserver listed in the delegating zone are authoritative, independently of them being the a primary or secondary nameserver.

Answer (score -1):

The Authoritative Answer bit is set in DNS replies by the server software in accordance with the DNS configuration put in place by the server administrator.  The particular syntax will depend on the DNS server being used.

For example, if the server is using bind9, the server administrator might designate a zone as `master`, per section 6.2.28.1 in the [BIND 9 Administrator Reference Manual](https://kb.isc.org/getAttach/41/AA-00843/Bv9ARM.pdf):

```
master    The server has a master copy of the data for the zone and will be
          able to provide authoritative answers for it.
```

Comment: Ok, but what about other zone types? for e.g. "slave"? If the server is set as "slave" for a zone does it set The Authoritative Answer bit in responses for that zone?